# ValueError: too many values to unpack, while using LMfit with solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, lmfit

I am facing `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` while optimizing parameters of a system of ODEs using `solve_ivp`. In fact I get the same error when I tried to use `solve_ivp` instead of `odeint` in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43073788/7271926), which you may use as a minimal working example since it has the same problem as far as I am concerned. The only changes I made to that code is swap positions of `y, t` in arguments for `f` and similarly while solving it using `solve_ivp` like so: `x = solve_ivp(f, t, x0, args=(paras,))` instead of using `odeint` in `g`

Here's the full code for the sake of convenience:

```py
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit


def f(t, y, paras):
    """
    Your system of differential equations
    """

    x1 = y[0]
    x2 = y[1]
    x3 = y[2]

    try:
        k0 = paras['k0'].value
        k1 = paras['k1'].value

    except KeyError:
        k0, k1 = paras
    # the model equations
    f0 = -k0 * x1
    f1 = k0 * x1 - k1 * x2
    f2 = k1 * x2
    return [f0, f1, f2]


def g(t, x0, paras):
    """
    Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,k) with initial condition x(0) = x0
    """
    x = solve_ivp(f, t, x0, args=(paras,))
    return x


def residual(paras, t, data):

    """
    compute the residual between actual data and fitted data
    """

    x0 = paras['x10'].value, paras['x20'].value, paras['x30'].value
    model = g(t, x0, paras)

    # you only have data for one of your variables
    x2_model = model[:, 1]
    return (x2_model - data).ravel()


# initial conditions
x10 = 5.
x20 = 0
x30 = 0
y0 = [x10, x20, x30]

# measured data
t_measured = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
x2_measured = np.array([0.000, 0.416, 0.489, 0.595, 0.506, 0.493, 0.458, 0.394, 0.335, 0.309])

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(t_measured, x2_measured, marker='o', color='b', label='measured data', s=75)

# set parameters including bounds; you can also fix parameters (use vary=False)
params = Parameters()
params.add('x10', value=x10, vary=False)
params.add('x20', value=x20, vary=False)
params.add('x30', value=x30, vary=False)
params.add('k0', value=0.2, min=0.0001, max=2.)
params.add('k1', value=0.3, min=0.0001, max=2.)

# fit model
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(t_measured, x2_measured), method='leastsq')  # leastsq nelder
# check results of the fit
data_fitted = g(np.linspace(0., 9., 100), y0, result.params)

# plot fitted data
plt.plot(np.linspace(0., 9., 100), data_fitted[:, 1], '-', linewidth=2, color='red', label='fitted data')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim([0, max(t_measured)])
plt.ylim([0, 1.1 * max(data_fitted[:, 1])])
# display fitted statistics
report_fit(result)

plt.show()
```

Here's the error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/swami/work/scrap/lmfit_example1.ipynb Cell 4 in <cell line: 67>()
     64 params.add('k1', value=0.3, min=0.0001, max=2.)
     66 # fit model
---> 67 result = minimize(residual, params, args=(t_measured, x2_measured), method='leastsq')  # leastsq nelder
     68 # check results of the fit
     69 data_fitted = g(np.linspace(0., 9., 100), y0, result.params)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dynamical/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:2600, in minimize(fcn, params, method, args, kws, iter_cb, scale_covar, nan_policy, reduce_fcn, calc_covar, max_nfev, **fit_kws)
   2460 """Perform the minimization of the objective function.
   2461 
   2462 The minimize function takes an objective function to be minimized,
   (...)
   2594 
   2595 """
   2596 fitter = Minimizer(fcn, params, fcn_args=args, fcn_kws=kws,
   2597                    iter_cb=iter_cb, scale_covar=scale_covar,
   2598                    nan_policy=nan_policy, reduce_fcn=reduce_fcn,
   2599                    calc_covar=calc_covar, max_nfev=max_nfev, **fit_kws)
-> 2600 return fitter.minimize(method=method)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dynamical/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:2369, in Minimizer.minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
   2366         if (key.lower().startswith(user_method) or
   2367                 val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
   2368             kwargs['method'] = val
-> 2369 return function(**kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dynamical/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:1693, in Minimizer.leastsq(self, params, max_nfev, **kws)
   1691 result.call_kws = lskws
   1692 try:
-> 1693     lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
   1694 except AbortFitException:
   1695     pass

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:410, in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    408 if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    409     args = (args,)
--> 410 shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    411 m = shape[0]
    413 if n > m:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:24, in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

File ~/miniconda3/envs/dynamical/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py:586, in Minimizer.__residual(self, fvars, apply_bounds_transformation)
    583     self.result.success = False
    584     raise AbortFitException(f"fit aborted: too many function evaluations {self.max_nfev}")
--> 586 out = self.userfcn(params, *self.userargs, **self.userkws)
    588 if callable(self.iter_cb):
    589     abort = self.iter_cb(params, self.result.nfev, out,
    590                          *self.userargs, **self.userkws)

/home/swami/work/scrap/lmfit_example1.ipynb Cell 4 in residual(paras, t, data)
     33 """
     34 compute the residual between actual data and fitted data
     35 """
     37 x0 = paras['x10'].value, paras['x20'].value, paras['x30'].value
---> 38 model = g(t, x0, paras)
     40 # you only have data for one of your variables
     41 x2_model = model[:, 1]

/home/swami/work/scrap/lmfit_example1.ipynb Cell 4 in g(t, x0, paras)
     23 def g(t, x0, paras):
     24     """
     25     Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,k) with initial condition x(0) = x0
     26     """
---> 27     x = solve_ivp(f, t, x0, args=(paras,))
     28     return x

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py:512, in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    507 if method not in METHODS and not (
    508         inspect.isclass(method) and issubclass(method, OdeSolver)):
    509     raise ValueError("`method` must be one of {} or OdeSolver class."
    510                      .format(METHODS))
--> 512 t0, tf = map(float, t_span)
    514 if args is not None:
    515     # Wrap the user's fun (and jac, if given) in lambdas to hide the
    516     # additional parameters.  Pass in the original fun as a keyword
    517     # argument to keep it in the scope of the lambda.
    518     try:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon noted, thanks. I added the traceback. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: According to the `solve_ivp` docs, `t_span 2-member sequence`, the `t` parameter is supposed to have 2 (exactly) elements.  The error indicates that you are giving it more than two (maybe a large array of times?)

Comment: I'm guessing `t` comes from `t_measured,` which is a 10 element array..  It's passing through several layers, so I can't be sure.  Anyways it's your responsibility to ensure that all parameters conform to the function specifications.

Comment: Thank you everybody. The problem was indeed that `t_measured` was supposed to have 2 elements. `solve_ivp` has a slightly different way of taking that argument vs `odeint`.